# Sequlize beforeCreated hook with a condition

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

In my user model I've define a lifecycle hook for encrypt the password with bycrypt.

```
beforeCreate: function(acc, next) {
    const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
    const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(acc.password, salt);
    acc.password = hash;
}
```

This works perfectly. But now I implement Oauth google login to the project. In that case I want to bypass this hook.

```
if (acc.password) {
    encrypt();
} else {
    skip();
}
```

I tried this

```
hooks: {
    beforeCreate: function(acc, next) {  
        if (acc.password) {
            const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
            const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(acc.password, salt);
            acc.password = hash;
        } else {
            return next
        }
    }
}
```

But this seems not work.

How do I skip the hook when req.body doesn't provide the password property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call next as a method like so: `next()`.